# Php grouping select query

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have persons associated with publications

My current query is this:

```
$query = "SELECT confAuth.personid, publicationconf.title FROM confAuth INNER JOIN publicationconf ON publicationconf.conferenceid = confAuth.conferenceid GROUP BY publicationconf.conferenceid";
```

It does group by conference id but only one person id is diplayed for each entry. Obviously, what I need is to display all person id's

Thanks in advance.

---

As a classmate just noted, this is our print statement and it is probably wrong. Any input to this.

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
    $rows = $result->num_rows;  
    if ($rows > 0)
    {
        for($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++)
        {
            if($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
            ?>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                <p><?php echo $row["personid"] . ", " . $row["title"]?></p>
```

Comment: Based on your query, will you have different `publicationconf.title`s for the same `confAuth.personid`? Also, include the table structures and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Use group_concat(confAuth.personid) to get a comma delimited list of all values in the grouped set.

However, since you are wanting one line item per personid/title combo, add the personid and the title to the group by clause.

Also, consider table aliases for readability.

```
$query = "SELECT ca.personid, pc.title 
FROM confAuth ca 
INNER JOIN publicationconf pc ON pc.conferenceid = ca.conferenceid 
GROUP BY pc.conferenceid, ca.personid, pc.title";
```

Comment: We need a one line per conference publication title, which will include all person ids.

Also, where to use group_concat()?

Comment: Did that help at all?

Comment: to be honest, I did not try it. We were out of time and there were more pressing issues.